# How to use git interactive rebase for signing off a series of commits

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit

I would like to **sign off all commits on a branch** that I have finished and want to send to an upstream project (e.g. via a pull request on GitHub).

A recommended way I've found is to use

```
git rebase -i [base-commit]
# Set all commits to "edit"
git commit --amend --signoff  # do this for all commits
```

How can I do this automatically, in one non-interactive command?

Comment: No need for an interactive rebase anymore: **`git rebase --signoff`** is available with Git 2.13 (Q2 2017): see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43726007/6309)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), no more "`git commit --amend --signoff`" needed:
See [commit 9f79524](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f79524a6af0527e380742ee103ca4fbcd440b42) (18 Apr 2017), and [commit 0fb3c4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fb3c4fc9a20cc3d7869d46bb8a774e4038fc62c), [commit b7cc705](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7cc7051f7f1cf9092fbddc828ff4ec249373046) (15 Apr 2017) by [Giuseppe Bilotta (`Oblomov`)](https://github.com/Oblomov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 768c7cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/768c7cb710a970a522320f712f028f17eabc66ed), 26 Apr 2017)</sup>

> ### `rebase`: pass `--[no-]signoff` option to `git am`
>
> This makes it easy to sign off a whole patchset before submission.

The [`git rebase` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9f79524a6af0527e380742ee103ca4fbcd440b42/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L368-L371) now includes:

```
--signoff:
```

> This flag is passed to '`git am`' to sign off all the rebased commits.
>   Incompatible with the `--interactive` option.

---

Update (one year later, May 2018) "`git rebase`" has learned to honor "`--signoff`" option when using
backends other than "`am`" (but not "`--preserve-merges`").

> ### `rebase`: extend `--signoff` support
>
> Allow `--signoff` to be used with `--interactive` and `--merge`.
>   In interactive mode only commits marked to be picked, edited or reworded
>   will be signed off.
>
> The main motivation for this patch was to allow one to run '`git rebase --exec "make check" --signoff`' which is useful when preparing a patch
>   series for publication and is more convenient than doing the signoff
>   with another --exec command.
>
> This change also allows `--root` without `--onto` to work with `--signoff` as well (`--root` with `--onto` was already supported).

It is also more robust:

> ### `rebase -p`: error out if `--signoff` is given
>
> `rebase --preserve-merges` does not support `--signoff` so error out
>   rather than just silently ignoring it so that the user knows the
>   commits will not be signed off.

Answer (score 6):

It turns that git aliases can do this quite nicely. Put into your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  # Usage: git signoff-rebase [base-commit]
  signoff-rebase = "!GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR='sed -i -re s/^pick/e/' sh -c 'git rebase -i $1 && while git rebase --continue; do git commit --amend --signoff --no-edit; done' -"
```

Here's also a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/nh2/66e1cd83a86da7fe43b1) for it.

You use it just like `git rebase`; the `pick`s are automatically flipped to `edit`s using `sed` and `--no-edit` makes sure to not open an editor for every single commit.